# How can I tell Rails routes to not serve a specific folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-routing

I have

```
get ":site_name/:page_name", to: "public_sites#show"
```

in routes.rb but this ends catching the `/assets/` folder in production, which I would like to avoid. Ideally, the `/assets/` folder would not be served by rails at all.

How can I achieve this while retaining the ability to process any :site_name with the exception of "assets"?

Or, what other approach could allow fast asset serving?

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Rails prepends the `/assets` route to your app's routes, so it should take precedence over your wildcard route. Assets should still be served OK in this scenario. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I found out the reason: `config.serve_static_files = false` in production, which prevents Rails from serving the assets folder. Added `gem 'rails_12factor'` in production per Heroku's recommendation on this issue and now the assets are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Routes accept [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints), so you should be able to do something like this (has not been tested):

```
get ":site_name/:page_name", to: "public_sites#show", constraints: {
  site_name: /^(?!assets$)/i 
}
```

If that doesn't work, you can also [pass a lambda as your constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) and check for the presence of "assets" there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Turns out rails routes constraints don't allow regex with anchors in it. Also, regex-es "not matching" something are proverbially hacky. That being said, I would've probably explored further in this direction if I had not found the culprit.